# Script doesn't work after transaction handling

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In a automatically generated script I have thousands of insert statements like the following...

```
INSERT INTO HR_EMP_VISA_INFO (V_PERSON_ID, V_VISA_STATUS, V_DEPENDANT, V_COUNTRY_OF_ISSUE, V_VISA_TYPE, V_ISSUE_DATE, V_EXPIRY_DATE, V_I94_EXPIRY_DATE, V_I94_EXTENDED, V_I94_EXTENDED_DATE, V_PLACE_OF_ISSUE, V_ENTRY_TYPE, V_DEPENDANT_NAME, V_RELATIONSHIP, V_APPROXIMATE_VISA_COST, V_ACTUAL_VISA_COST, V_CURRENCY, V_VISA_UTILIZED, V_REMARKS, V_VISA_NUMBER) 
VALUES (4190.0, 'Active', 'N', 'USA', 'H1B', '2013/06/25 00:00:00', '2015/09/30 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Sydney', 'Multiple', NULL, NULL, '25700.00', NULL, 'LKR', 'N', NULL, 'V1000001');
```

If I put begin .... commit; end; this want work i.e. nothing is inserted in to the table.

ex:

```
begin
// all insert statements
//
commit;
end;
```

How to include transaction handling in the above script? My main concern is to roll back the transactions if any of the above insert statements fail and also if possible to minimize the time taken for this whole script. Now it takes more than 10 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 1):

To handle rollback and make transaction atomic you have already almost done, look below.
To make insert faster you could insert "APPEND_VALUES" hint but as docs says:

> In direct-path INSERT, data is appended to the end of the table,
>   rather than using existing space currently allocated to the table. As
>   a result, direct-path INSERT can be considerably faster than
>   conventional INSERT.

Snippet:

```
set serveroutput on;

begin

// all insert statements with APPEND_VALUES hint
//eg.
INSERT /*+ APPEND_VALUES */ INTO HR_EMP_VISA_INFO (V_PERSON_ID, V_VISA_STATUS, V_DEPENDANT, V_COUNTRY_OF_ISSUE, V_VISA_TYPE, V_ISSUE_DATE, V_EXPIRY_DATE, V_I94_EXPIRY_DATE, V_I94_EXTENDED, V_I94_EXTENDED_DATE, V_PLACE_OF_ISSUE, V_ENTRY_TYPE, V_DEPENDANT_NAME, V_RELATIONSHIP, V_APPROXIMATE_VISA_COST, V_ACTUAL_VISA_COST, V_CURRENCY, V_VISA_UTILIZED, V_REMARKS, V_VISA_NUMBER) 
VALUES (4190.0, 'Active', 'N', 'USA', 'H1B', '2013/06/25 00:00:00', '2015/09/30 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Sydney', 'Multiple', NULL, NULL, '25700.00', NULL, 'LKR', 'N', NULL, 'V1000001');
//
commit;
exception when others then
rollback;
dbms_output.put_line('Insert failed due to: '|| SQLERRM);
end;
```

Comment: First of all, hint APPEND does nothing if used with insert/values. See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6087912900346548365 for example. Hint APPLY_VALUES may be used here, but I doubt if it have sense.

Comment: Thanks for remark! In that case APPEND would by silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Ten minutes is a much for thousands of records... It's enough for millions of records. First of all, you should check if you have triggers on this table or maybe lot of indexes and foreign keys; you should found if any of this makes speed so low.

If you wish to speed up your inserts, you should use bulk inserts and/or direct path inserts. The best way is to generate formatted data file instead of SQL script and to use Oracle SQL Loader for fast loading of this data into database. This also makes question about transactions senseless (using SQL Loader you can select commit policy as you wish).

Generally, I'd disadvice you about full rollback. It's not smart to rollback 1'000'000 records and reload them all after correcting.

You can read about bulk/direct inserts in PL/SQL at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html